# Make a frame with subplots in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to make a figure which consist of a frame with 4 figures, but in each figure there are three subplots. I am using the current version of Matplotlib

I show my code in order to do each individual figure, the point as I comment before, is how put 4 of this plots together in order to make a single figure

```
filename1 = "file1.txt"
filename2 = "file2.txt"
filename3 = "file3.txt" 

datalist1 = np.loadtxt(filename1)
datalist2 = np.loadtxt(filename2)
datalist3 = np.loadtxt(filename3)


f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True, sharey=True)

#First subplot

ax1.plot(datalist1[:,0], datalist1[:,1], 'k-')
ax1.plot(datalist2[:,0], datalist2[:,1], 'b-')
ax1.plot(datalist2[:,0], datalist2[:,2], 'g-')
ax1.plot(datalist2[:,0], datalist2[:,3], 'r-')
ax1.plot(datalist3[:,0], datalist3[:,1], 'k--')

ax1.set_ylim(-1.2, 1.2)
ax1.set_xlim(0, 10)

major_ticks_x = np.arange(0.0, 11, 2.0)                                        
minor_ticks_x = np.arange(0.0, 11, 1.0)   

major_ticks_y = np.arange(-1, 1.05, 1.0)                                         
minor_ticks_y = np.arange(-1, 1.05, 0.25)   

ax1.set_yticks(major_ticks_y)                                                       
ax1.set_yticks(minor_ticks_y, minor=True) 

#Second subplot

ax2.plot(datalist1[:,0], datalist1[:,2], 'k-')
ax2.plot(datalist2[:,0], datalist2[:,4], 'b-')
ax2.plot(datalist2[:,0], datalist2[:,5], 'g-')
ax2.plot(datalist2[:,0], datalist2[:,6], 'r-')
ax2.plot(datalist3[:,0], datalist3[:,1], 'k--')

ax2.set_ylim(-1.2, 1.2)
ax2.set_xlim(0, 10)                       
ax2.set_yticks(major_ticks_y)                                                       
ax2.set_yticks(minor_ticks_y, minor=True) 

#Third subplot

ax3.plot(datalist1[:,0], datalist1[:,3], 'k-')
ax3.plot(datalist2[:,0], datalist2[:,7], 'b-')
ax3.plot(datalist2[:,0], datalist2[:,8], 'g-')
ax3.plot(datalist2[:,0], datalist2[:,9], 'r-')
ax3.plot(datalist3[:,0], datalist3[:,1], 'k--')
ax3.set_ylim(-1.2, 1.2)
ax3.set_xlim(0, 10)

ax3.set_yticks(major_ticks_y)                                                       
ax3.set_yticks(minor_ticks_y, minor=True) 
ax3.set_xticks(major_ticks_x)                                                       
ax3.set_xticks(minor_ticks_x, minor=True)

ax3.set_xlabel(r"$t$")

f.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.0)
plt.setp([a.get_xticklabels() for a in f.axes[:-1]], visible=False)
```

The plot that I want to obtain is somtehing like this, in a single figure:

[image]

Somebody knows how can be do it?? Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Any reason you want 4 figures or 12 subplots in one figure with shared x-axis will do? Because really it can be done using 12 subplots in one figure.

Comment: Ah that's a good point, in fact I preffer to put the figures shared x and y-axes, but must be something that allows to distinguis each figure, like a),b),c),d).

Comment: Maybe you rephrase your question given that in matplotlib a canvas consists of exactly one figure and that figure can have arbitrary many subplots. Placing a figure inside a figure is simply not possible.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'll bite. It is unclear what you want, but I assume you want 12 subplots (6 rows, 2 columns) grouped into 4 groups with shared x-axis.

As usual creating the subplots and plotting is easy. Sharing x-axis is straightforward as well, but requires some manual work. You can either set up the shared x-axis during the subplot creation or modify it after. I think modifying after is simpler.

Sorry for the manual part in the middle - it is possible to automate obviously.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
fig, axx = plt.subplots(6, 2, figsize=(10,14))

## merge axis
axx[0, 0].get_shared_x_axes().join(axx[0, 0], axx[2, 0])
axx[0, 0].set_xticklabels([])
axx[1, 0].get_shared_x_axes().join(axx[1, 0], axx[2, 0])
axx[1, 0].set_xticklabels([])

axx[0, 1].get_shared_x_axes().join(axx[0, 1], axx[2, 1])
axx[0, 1].set_xticklabels([])
axx[1, 1].get_shared_x_axes().join(axx[1, 1], axx[2, 1])
axx[1, 1].set_xticklabels([])

axx[3, 0].get_shared_x_axes().join(axx[3, 0], axx[5, 0])
axx[3, 0].set_xticklabels([])
axx[4, 0].get_shared_x_axes().join(axx[4, 0], axx[5, 0])
axx[4, 0].set_xticklabels([])

axx[3, 1].get_shared_x_axes().join(axx[3, 1], axx[5, 1])
axx[3, 1].set_xticklabels([])
axx[4, 1].get_shared_x_axes().join(axx[4, 1], axx[5, 1])
axx[4, 1].set_xticklabels([])

# plot some data
for i, row in enumerate(axx):
    for j, cell in enumerate(row):
        if i <= 2:
            cell.plot(np.random.rand(100))
        else:
            cell.plot(np.random.rand(200))
```

Here is the result.
[image]